# What was the rational for the design of NULL boolean expression

Tags: sql

What was the rationale for this in the design of SQL (evaluated in postgres, but seems likely the same in all flavors:

```
select NULL OR TRUE  --> True

select NULL OR FALSE  --> NULL (expected false, but is NULL)
```

Comment: There is no Boolean type in oracle SQL.

Comment: `null or true` is indeed valid standard SQL and Postgres fully implements a `boolean` data type. Your assumption that this would be true for other DBMS is wrong however. Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, DB2 - none of them support a `boolean` data type. The only other DBMS I know of are Firebird, H2 and HSQLDB

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NULL` means you don't know what the value is. It might be true, it might be false. We don't know yet.

`NULL OR False` is easier here. This expression clearly can't evaluate to `True` at this point. On the other hand, it's not definitely `False` yet, either. We don't yet have enough information to solve the whole expression, and so `NULL` is the only result that makes sense.

`NULL OR TRUE`, on the other hand, *does* provide enough information to solve the whole expression. With an `OR` condition, if either side is true, then logically the full result is true; it doesn't matter what the other side does. Even if that `NULL` eventually turned out to be a `False`, the expression result still evaluates to `True`. There is nothing you can do with `NULL` to make that expression become `False`.

And, just for clarity, it's worthwhile to also look at `NULL AND TRUE` and `NULL AND FALSE`. The former will also evaluated to `NULL`, because, again, we don't have enough information yet to fully solve the expression, while the latter will evaluated to `False`, because no matter how `NULL` works out the expression can't become `True`.

If you really want to get confused, think about what happens when you make a `NULL = NULL` equality comparison. The real result is that we don't know yet (NULL), but if you force the issue, the database will evaluate the expression as False: NULL is not equal to itself.

Comment: Doh! Makes sense.